# Failed building JavaScript bundle. Unable to resolve module ./reanimated2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem that prevents me from continuing my react antive project:
is you can offer me some ideas please.
The program works in my partner's environment but not in my home.

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve module ./reanimated2 from /home/salami/Documents/COURS_PARIS_SACLAY/semestre6/projet_GLA/OC_FullStack/Eugloh_frontend/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/Animated.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/reanimated2(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/reanimated2/index(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
> 1 | import { Image, ScrollView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
  2 | import Easing from './Easing';
  3 | import AnimatedClock from './core/AnimatedClock';
  4 | import AnimatedValue from './core/AnimatedValue';
```

Comment: please, propositions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check if you're using `react-native-reanimated` v1 and not v2
- Uninstalled and install `react-native-reanimated` v1 again
- Run `npx react-native start --reset-cache` after that `npx react-native run-android` or `npx react-native run-ios`

[Source](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1798)